# how to shuffle XML layouts

Tags: android, xml, random

I'm very new in developing an application in Android

*How can i randomly change the current activity `Layout` when i click a `Button`* ? i don't really know how and where to start coding

```
public class RandomSample extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button random = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int [] layouts = {R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, R.layout.layout3};
    Random r = new Random();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(r.nextInt(layouts.length));
        }
    });
}
}
```

here's what I did but noting seems to be working at all

Comment: @Onur A. i have tried your code but nothing seems to be working

Comment: you should optimize it for yourself i just wrote easy to customize dummy code

Comment: i see. can you give me guidelines or some pointers on how to properly create such method? thank you.

Comment: There's a bug in your posted code, which I've fixed in my answer below.

Comment: inside your related button onclick code it should be setContentView(layouts[r.nextInt(layouts.length)]); in previous version you passed a random number to function; now you access that particular layout id inside that array

Comment: @user3149781 If one of the responses solved your problem, you should accept an answer in order to help people who have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array of ids of layouts and then change it `setContentView()`

```
int[] layouts={R.layout.l1, R.layout.l2, R.layout.l3, R.layout.l4};
Random r=new Random();
```

in your `onClick()` method of particular button

```
setContentView(r.nextInt(layouts.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your posted is that you are trying to set the random index as the content view rather than its associated layout. I've modified your code below.

```
private static final int[] layouts = {R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, R.layout.layout3};
Random r = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button random = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This is just a number 0 - 2. It should not be set to content view.
            int index = r.nextInt(layouts.length);
            int nextLayout = layouts[index];
            setContentView(nextLayout);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                      setContentView(R.layout.second);
                      }
              });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each id mapped on R class is an integer. So, you can use the method nextInt() from Random class to pick a random layout.

Try something like this:

```
int firstLayout = R.layout.l1; //your first layout
int numberOfLayouts = 5; // the number of layouts that you have

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random r = new Random();
        setContentView(r.nextInt(numberOfLayouts) + firstLayout);
    }
};
```